# Regarding summation with a for loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to get the user to input a birth date and then add the individual ints in those numbers. Also, if a sum of any of these digits is greater than or equal to 10, the loop repeats and the process runs again for the value. Here's my code so far

```
if (sumYear >= 10):
    sumYear2=0
    for num in str(sumYear):
        sumYear2 += int(num)
print(sumYear2)
```

This works however I think it would be better done as a loop. And if there's some way I won't have to use something like `sumYear2` that would be great. Note, I don't think I can use the `sum()` function.

Thanks guys for the help. I'm having an issue though. I'm not sure why this code isn't being evaluated when I provide the month as 02 and the day as 30

```
while True:
        year=input("Please enter the year you were born: ")
        month=input("Please enter the month you were born: ")
        day=input("Please enter the day you were born: ")
        if(int(month)==2 and int(day)<=29):
            break
        elif(int(month)==1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12 and int(day)<=31 ):
            break
        elif(int(month)==4 or 6 or 9 or 11 and int(day)<=30):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input")
```

Comment: To your edit: In general you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if it is not a subquestion of the original one.

Comment: Specify whether you use Python 2.x or 3.x. Your code looks like Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Too much work.

```
singledigitsum = (int(inputvalue) - 1) % 9 + 1
```

Note that this will fail for numbers less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

[@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861671/regarding-summation-with-a-for-loop/7861698#7861698) provides the formula. But if there were none then your code as a loop without using `sumYear2` could look like:

```
while sumYear >= 10:
      sumYear = sum(map(int, str(sumYear)))
```

If you're not allowed to use `sum` (a homework) then:

```
while sumYear >= 10:
      s = 0
      for d in str(sumYear):
          s += int(d)
      sumYear = s
```

---

For the second question assuming Python 3:

```
while True:
    try:
        year  = int(input("Please enter the year you were born: "))
        month = int(input("Please enter the month you were born: "))
        day   = int(input("Please enter the day you were born: "))
        birthday = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("error: %s" % (e,))
    else:
        break
```

---

If you are not allowed to use try/except then:

```
year  = get_int("Please enter the year you were born: ",
                datetime.MINYEAR, datetime.MAXYEAR)
month = get_int("Please enter the month you were born: ",
                 1, 12)
day   = get_int("Please enter the day you were born: ",
                1, number_of_days_in_month(year, month))
birthday = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

Where `get_int()`:

```
def get_int(prompt, minvalue, maxvalue):
    """Get an integer from user."""
    while True:
        s = input(prompt)
        if s.strip().isdigit():
           v = int(s)
           if minvalue <= v <= maxvalue:
              return v
        print("error: the input is not an integer in range [%d, %d]" % (
            minvalue, maxvalue))
```

And `number_of_days_in_month()`:

```
# number of days in a month disregarding leap years
ndays = [0]*13
ndays[1::2] = [31]*len(ndays[1::2])  # odd months
ndays[::2] = [30]*len(ndays[::2])    # even months
ndays[2] = 28 # February
ndays[8] = 31 # August 
# fill other months here ...

def number_of_days_in_month(year, month):
    return ndays[month] + (month == 2 and isleap(year))
```

Comment: thanks so much! Super helpful. Unfortunately, I dont think we can use a try/except

Comment: @user979616: I've added variant without try/except.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
>>> d=123456
>>> sum(int(c) for c in str(d))
21
```

Comment: the final sum must be less than 10.